# Mysql Date fomat

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a date format coming from CSV file. The format looks like "2013/01/01 9:47 PM". I want to save that information into timestamp. How can I achieve that using MySQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer

"select str_to_date('2013/01/01 9:47 PM','%Y/%m/%d %h:%i %p')"  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

```
UPDATE field SET new_date = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(old_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013/01/01 9:47 PM');
```

Here is the usefull link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

in `insert` use this as value for desired column:

```
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2013/01/01 9:47 PM'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help You,please go through http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/06/15/converting-mysql-str-to-date-function.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Apr 15 2012 12:00AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')),'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i:%p')


SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('Apr 15 2012 12:00AM', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//In PHP
$date = new DateTime('2013/01/01 9:47 PM');
echo $date2 = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//output
2013-01-01 21:47:00
```